# How to change size of QGraphicsPixmap using animation?

Tags: c++, qt, qpropertyanimation

I have class named Pixmap deriving from QGraphicsPixmapItem and StartScreen class deriving from QGraphicsScene. I want to use animations (QPropertyAnimation class) to resize displayed image in certain time range. Other actions like setting position or rotation aren't problem but I couldn't find any property like size (e.g. setSize() method). How can I do that in the other way? Thanks for advance.

```
StartScreen::StartScreen(int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
{
    setSceneRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QImage(":/images/background.png")));

    Pixmap * logo = new Pixmap(":/images/logo.png");
    addItem(logo);
    logo->setPos((windowWidth - logo->pixmap().width()) / 2, (windowWidth - logo->pixmap().width()) / 2 - 75);

    //QPropertyAnimation * animation = new QPropertyAnimation(logo, "");
}
```

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

`QPropertyAnimation` applies to Qt Properties, but only objects that inherit from `QObject` have Qt properties, so if you want to use animations you can use `QGraphicsObject` and create your own item, or create a class that inherits the item you want and `QObject`.

```
class Pixmap: public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem{

    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal scale READ scale WRITE setScale)
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal rotation READ rotation WRITE setRotation)
    Q_PROPERTY(QPointF pos READ pos WRITE setPos)
public:
    using QGraphicsPixmapItem::QGraphicsPixmapItem;
};
```

In the previous example, take advantage of the fact that `QGraphicsItem`, and therefore its derived classes, have the methods `pos()`, `setPos()`, `scale()`, `setScale()`, `rotation()` and `setRotation()`, so only use them in `Q_PROPERTY`.

In the next part I show an example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView w;

    QGraphicsScene scene(0, 0, 640, 480);
    w.setScene(&scene);
    w.show();

    Pixmap* logo = new Pixmap(QPixmap(":/image.jpg"));
    scene.addItem(logo);

    QSequentialAnimationGroup group;

    QPropertyAnimation animation_scale(logo, "scale");
    animation_scale.setDuration(1000);
    animation_scale.setStartValue(2.0);
    animation_scale.setEndValue(0.1);

    QPropertyAnimation animation_pos(logo, "pos");
    animation_pos.setDuration(1000);
    animation_pos.setStartValue(QPointF(0, 0));
    animation_pos.setEndValue(QPointF(100, 100));

    /**
    * it must indicate the center of rotation,
    * in this case it will be the center of the item
    */
    logo->setTransformOriginPoint(logo->boundingRect().center());
    QPropertyAnimation animation_rotate(logo, "rotation");
    animation_rotate.setDuration(1000);
    animation_rotate.setStartValue(0);
    animation_rotate.setEndValue(360);

    group.addAnimation(&animation_scale);
    group.addAnimation(&animation_pos);
    group.addAnimation(&animation_rotate);

    group.start();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49094823/49094823-1) there is an example

Or you can use QVariantAnimation instead of QPropertyAnimation:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView w;

    QGraphicsScene scene(0, 0, 640, 480);
    w.setScene(&scene);
    w.show();

    QGraphicsPixmapItem* logo = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(":/image.jpg"));
    scene.addItem(logo);

    QSequentialAnimationGroup group;

    QVariantAnimation animation_scale;
    animation_scale.setDuration(1000);
    animation_scale.setStartValue(2.0);
    animation_scale.setEndValue(0.5);

    QObject::connect(&animation_scale, &QVariantAnimation::valueChanged, [logo](const QVariant &value){
        logo->setScale(value.toReal());
    });

    animation_scale.start();

    QVariantAnimation animation_pos;
    animation_pos.setDuration(1000);
    animation_pos.setStartValue(QPointF(0, 0));
    animation_pos.setEndValue(QPointF(100, 100));

    QObject::connect(&animation_pos, &QVariantAnimation::valueChanged, [logo](const QVariant &value){
        logo->setPos(value.toPointF());
    });

    /**
    * it must indicate the center of rotation,
    * in this case it will be the center of the item
    */

    logo->setTransformOriginPoint(logo->boundingRect().center());
    QVariantAnimation animation_rotate;
    animation_rotate.setDuration(1000);
    animation_rotate.setStartValue(0);
    animation_rotate.setEndValue(360);

    QObject::connect(&animation_rotate, &QVariantAnimation::valueChanged, [logo](const QVariant &value){
        logo->setRotation(value.toReal());
    });

    group.addAnimation(&animation_scale);
    group.addAnimation(&animation_pos);
    group.addAnimation(&animation_rotate);

    group.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49094823/49094823-2) there is an example